# Can I setup a different number of workers for each individual server using Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

We have 4 delayed job processes and 4 ruby processes running on one of our application servers. The other application servers have 8 workers. Currently we use the NGINX configuration file on that server to set the 4 ruby workers and Capistrano to manage the 4 delayed jobs. On our other application servers we have 8 workers setup through the NGINX configuration file.

I am looking in to upgrading to Unicorn. The configuration file for Unicorn is in the application where as the NGINX configuration file is stored in Linux. Is there a way to set a different amount of worker processes per server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set it in your environment variable.

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["UNICORN_WORKERS"] || 5)
```